# How to save an intent object and later retrieve it

Tags: android, android-intent

I'd like to save an Intent object which has it's own set of properties associated with it and then later retrieve it so that I just have to write

```
startActivity(intentObject);
```

What can be the best practice to do so?
I've read about Google Gson and object serialization/parcelable implementation but couldn't get a handle on it.

example scenario:

**Activity 1**

```
Intent abc = new Intent ();
abc.setClass(); //set class here
abc.setExtra(); //set some extras
```

**Some other activity**

```
//code to retrieve abc Intent object
```

PS.  - I'm aware of communication between activities through intents but this is not a case of communication between two activities.

**EDIT 1**

Keep in mind that the intent is being set up by another user so I don't exactly know what are the properties associated with it. Also converting it into a Json String or Serializing/making it Parcelable is not something I'm looking for. Any ideas?

**EDIT 2**

What I have tried so far is to convert that Intentobject to a Json using the [Jackson library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core)  and then later on setting a new intent by parsing that json. What I am afraid of is loosing some important attributes that might not be converted into Json.

Thanks,
Shantanu

Comment: why not use parcelable to send data between activities?

Comment: What do you mean "this is not a case of communication between two activities"? There is `Activity 1` and there is `some other activity`. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes it can be done but in this case I do not know the set of attributes or properties associated with that intent. ( the intent is being set up by another user). @hakim

Comment: @th3pat3l . It means that this is not a case of simple communication between two activities ( Act. 1 and Act. 2). Like when we switch from activity 1 to 2 we use startactivity in Actvity 1 and then use getIntent in Activity 2.

Comment: Ok that was my bad. I believe I just misread your original post. Ok so If i understand it correctly, you want to have an object (`Intent`) ready so when you are in some other `Activity`, you can call that Intent object to start an `Activity`?

Comment: Infact can't we just imitate something like     Intent  = getIntent(), to get the intent object. Only in this case we'd have to make the intent object as globally accessible?

Comment: what you want exactly !! please explain more..

Comment: @th3pat3l yes exactly.

Comment: @Radhey Suppose you are communicating between two activities using an intent (A1 ---> A2) . Now, suppose you are in other activity (say A3) and you want to do ( A3 ---> A2). What can be the best way to do this without adding much of the boiler plate code.

Comment: you want to pass data from A3->A2 ,with out creating new object of intent right!?

Comment: @Radhey Yes exactly. Any ideas?

Comment: you have to use Parcelable or a Serializable object in to your next activity , I guess without doing it ,you can not store old object value .but I didn't see any usage ,why you want this in case of intent object .you can do it easily with creating new object .

Comment: @Radhey  
Can't we just imitate something like Intent = getIntent(), to get the intent object. Only in this case we'd have to make the intent object as globally accessible?

Comment: I never tried yet ! if you got any solution then let us inform for knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching for many days I got to know that although there are many methods of converting an Intent into a byte stream there are no proper ways to store and retrieve an intent object that has alien(to us) attributes associated with it.
What follows is my own logic. I am converting the intentobcject into a json string first using Jackson and then I'm parsing that json and setting attributes to a new intent object.

For intent to json:

```
public String intentToJSON(Context con,Intent intent) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String getClassName = null;
    getClassName = intent.getComponent().getClassName();
    String getContextName = null;
    getContextName = con.getClass().getName() + ".this";
    HashMap<String, String> makeInsideJsonArray = new HashMap<String, String>();

    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hashMap.put("className",getClassName);
    hashMap.put("context",getContextName);
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
        Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
        Log.d("SappsnoopDog",""+keys.size());
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = it.next();

            Log.d("Sapptagdog","TYPE   " + bundle.get(key).toString());
            Log.d("NERVE",""+bundle.get(key).getClass().getAnnotations());


            String type = bundle.get(key).getClass().getSimpleName();
            Log.d("SappDogTAG",key + " OF TYPE " + type);
            switch (type) {
                case "String":
                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+ LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR +bundle.get(key).toString());
                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;
                case "String[]":
                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+bundle.get(key).toString().replace(" ",""));
                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;
                case "Integer":
                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+bundle.get(key).toString());

                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;
                case "Double":
                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+bundle.get(key).toString());
                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;
                case  "double[]":

                    double[] newDouble = (double[]) bundle.get(key);
                    String fromDouble = Arrays.toString(newDouble);
                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+fromDouble.replace(" ",""));
                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;
                case "int[]":
                    int[] newArray = (int[]) bundle.get(key);
                    String fromArray = Arrays.toString(newArray);
                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+fromArray.replace(" ",""));
                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;
                case "Boolean":
                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+bundle.get(key).toString());
                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;
                case "boolean[]":

                    boolean[] newBool = (boolean[]) bundle.get(key);
                    String fromBool = Arrays.toString(newBool);
                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+fromBool.replace(" ",""));
                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;
                case "Char":
                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+bundle.get(key).toString());
                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;
                case "char[]":

                    char[] newChar = (char[]) bundle.get(key);
                    String fromChar = Arrays.toString(newChar);
                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+fromChar.replace(" ",""));
                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;
                case "CharSequence":
                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+bundle.get(key).toString());
                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;
                case "charsequence[]":

                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+bundle.get(key).toString().replace(" ",""));
                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;
                case "Byte":
                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+bundle.get(key).toString());
                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;
                case "byte[]":

                    byte[] newByte = (byte[]) bundle.get(key);
                    String fromByte = Arrays.toString(newByte);
                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+fromByte.replace(" ",""));
                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;
                case "Float":
                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+bundle.get(key).toString());
                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;
                case "float[]":

                    float[] newFloat = (float[]) bundle.get(key);
                    String fromFloat = Arrays.toString(newFloat);
                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+fromFloat.replace(" ",""));
                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;
                case "Short":
                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+bundle.get(key).toString());
                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;
                case "short[]":

                    short[] newShort = (short[]) bundle.get(key);
                    String fromShort = Arrays.toString(newShort);
                    fromShort = fromShort.replace(" ","");
                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+fromShort.replace(" ",""));
                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;
                case "Long":
                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+bundle.get(key).toString());
                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;
                case "long[]":

                    long[] newLong = (long[]) bundle.get(key);
                    String fromLong = Arrays.toString(newLong);
                    makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+bundle.get(key).toString().replace(" ",""));
                    Log.d("SappDogTAG","bool array");
                    break;

                case "ArrayList":
                    ArrayList<Object> obj = (ArrayList<Object>) bundle.get(key);
                    Object[] objArr = obj.toArray();
                    if(objArr[0] instanceof Integer){
                        ArrayList<Integer> newIntegerArray = bundle.getIntegerArrayList(key);
                        makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+"Integer"+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+newIntegerArray.toString().replace(" ",""));

                    }else if(objArr[0] instanceof String){
                        ArrayList<String> newStringArray = bundle.getStringArrayList(key);

                        makeInsideJsonArray.put(key,type+"String"+LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR+newStringArray.toString().replace(" ",""));

                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    // whatever
            }

            hashMap.put(key, bundle.get(key).toString());
        }
    }
    String passArray = mapper.writeValueAsString(makeInsideJsonArray);
    hashMap.put("intentExtras",passArray);
    Log.d("GOGTAD",""+passArray);

    String intentString  = mapper.writeValueAsString(intent);
    Log.d("IntentString", "" + mapper.writeValueAsString(hashMap));
    StringBuilder a1S = new StringBuilder(mapper.writeValueAsString(hashMap));
    a1S.deleteCharAt(mapper.writeValueAsString(hashMap).length()-1);
    a1S.append(",");
    String s1t = a1S.toString();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(intentString);
    sb.deleteCharAt(0);
    String retrString = sb.toString();
    StringBuilder newS = new StringBuilder();
    newS.append(s1t);
    newS.append(retrString);
    Log.d("Insnsns",newS.toString());
    return newS.toString();
}
```

and for json to intent:

```
 public Intent jsonToINTENT(String JSONString) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSONString.toString());
    String toArray = jsonObject.get("intentExtras").toString();
    String contextName = "com.hanuor.sapphiredemo";
    String className = jsonObject.get("className").toString();
    Log.d("Insass",className.toString());

    Intent setIntent = new Intent();
    setIntent.setClassName(contextName, className);
    HashMap<String, String> extrasHash = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JSONObject issueObj = new JSONObject(toArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < issueObj.length(); i++) {
        extrasHash.put(issueObj.names().getString(i), issueObj.get(issueObj.names().getString(i)).toString());
    }
    Iterator it = extrasHash.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        //add conditions  and checks here

        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        String currentKey = (String) pair.getKey();
        Log.d("HAHA",""+currentKey);
        String[] getValuethroughSplit = pair.getValue().toString().split(LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPERATOR);
        String dataType = getValuethroughSplit[0];
        String  value = (String) getValuethroughSplit[2];
        Log.d("Insamareen",getValuethroughSplit.length + " " +dataType+ " " +value.toString());
        switch (dataType) {
            case "String":
                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey,(String) value);
                break;
            case "String[]":
                String comp1 = value.substring(1,value.length()-1);
                String[] comp2 = comp1.split(",");
                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey,comp2);
                break;
            case "Integer":
                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey,Integer.parseInt(value));
                break;
            case "Double":

                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey,Double.parseDouble(value));

                break;
            case  "double[]":
                String compDouble1 = value.substring(1,value.length()-1);
                String[] compDoub2 = compDouble1.split(",");
                double[] db = new double[compDoub2.length];
                for(int i = 0; i<compDoub2.length; i++){
                    db[i] = Double.parseDouble(compDoub2[i]);
                }
                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey,db);
                break;
            case "int[]":
                String compInt1 = value.substring(1,value.length()-1);
                String[] compInt2 = compInt1.split(",");
                int[] intVal = new int[compInt2.length];
                for(int i = 0; i<compInt2.length; i++){
                    intVal[i] = Integer.parseInt(compInt2[i]);
                }
                Log.d("Hankey",intVal.toString());
                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey,intVal);

                break;
            case "Boolean":
                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey,Boolean.valueOf(value));

                break;
            case "boolean[]":
                String compB1 = value.substring(1,value.length()-1);
                String[] compB2 = compB1.split(",");
                boolean[] BVal = new boolean[compB2.length];
                for(int i = 0; i<compB2.length; i++){
                    BVal[i] =Boolean.parseBoolean(compB2[i]);
                }
                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey, value);

                break;
            case "Char":
                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey,value);

                break;
            case "char[]":

                String ch1 = value.substring(1,value.length()-1);
                String[] ch2 = ch1.split(",");
                String newS = null;
                for(int i = 0; i<ch2.length; i++){
                    newS = newS + ch2[i];
                }
                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey,newS.toCharArray());

                break;
            case "CharSequence":
                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey,(CharSequence) value);

                break;
            case "Charsequence[]":
                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey,value.toString());

                break;
            case "Byte":
                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey,Byte.valueOf(value));

                break;
            case "byte[]":
                String by = value.substring(1,value.length()-1);
                String[] by2 = by.split(",");
                byte[] by3 = new byte[by2.length];
                for(int i = 0; i<by2.length; i++){
                    by3[i] =Byte.parseByte(by2[i]);
                }
                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey,by3);

                break;
            case "Float":
                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey,Float.valueOf(value));

                break;
            case "float[]":
                String fl = value.substring(1,value.length()-1);
                String[] fl2 = fl.split(",");
                float[] fl3 = new float[fl2.length];
                for(int i = 0; i<fl2.length; i++){
                    fl3[i] =Float.parseFloat(fl2[i]);
                }
                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey,fl3);

                break;
            case "Short":
                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey,Short.valueOf(value));

                break;
            case "short[]":
                String sh = value.substring(1,value.length()-1);
                String[] sh2 = sh.split(",");
                short[] sh3 = new short[sh2.length];
                for(int i = 0; i<sh2.length; i++){
                    sh3[i] =Short.parseShort(sh2[i]);
                }
                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey,sh3);

                break;
            case "Long":
                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey,Long.valueOf(value));

                break;
            case "long[]":
                String ll = value.substring(1,value.length()-1);
                String[] ll2 = ll.split(",");
                long[] ll3 = new long[ll2.length];
                for(int i = 0; i<ll2.length; i++){
                    ll3[i] =Long.parseLong(ll2[i]);
                }
                setIntent.putExtra(currentKey,ll3);

                break;

            case "ArrayListString":
                Log.d("Hankey",currentKey+" ");
                String arrL = value.substring(1,value.length()-1);
                String[] arrl2 = arrL.split(",");
                ArrayList<String> arrStr = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < arrl2.length; i++) {
                    arrStr.add(arrl2[i]);
                }
                setIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(currentKey, arrStr);

                break;
            case "ArrayListInteger":
                String arL = value.substring(1,value.length()-1);
                String[] arl2 = arL.split(",");
                ArrayList<Integer> arrInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for(int i = 0; i<arl2.length; i++){
                    arrInt.add(Integer.parseInt(arl2[i]));
                }

                setIntent.putIntegerArrayListExtra(currentKey,arrInt);

                break;
            default:
                // whatever
        }
    }
    return setIntent;
}
```

There is still a lot more yet to be implemented while parsing the Json. I've done this just to set up the associated values.

Comment: what is `LibraryDatabase.JSONSEPARATOR`?

Answer (score 0):

As your comment said, yes, you can make the Intent object globally accessible but it's not exactly the proper way to do it. You don't know when that can be called again. While it's just "waiting" there, it's using memory and it's a temporary solution if app is closed.

I wouldn't call this the "best" way but it works:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString("class_name", SomeOtherActivity.class.getSimpleName());
        // add your other properties here
        editor.apply();
        // then continue with your work, maybe start the new activity
    }
});
```

Then from somewhere else, you can do this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext();
String className = preferences.getString("class_name", "");
// get your other properties here

if(!className.isEmpty()) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Class.forName(className));
        // add the retreived properties here
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not sure it answers my query. Please check the edit.